# how to calculate date range in sql using interval

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a two tables in one table I have a column contravention date  and in other table  i have NTO date column 
 now I want to find how can I retrieve data from tables  where NTOdate is greater than 50 days of contravention date.
but when I run this query i get error as  Incorrect syntax near '50'.

```
SELECT [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].t_vrm
  ,[ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].t_zone_name
  ,[ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].t_street_name
FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]
INNER JOIN [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events]
  ON [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_system_ref] = [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_number]
WHERE [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_camera_ticket] = '0'
  AND [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_date_time_issued] >= convert(DATETIME, '2012/10/01', 101)
  AND [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_event_code] = '300'
  AND [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_date] > DATE (DATE_SUB([ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_date_time_issued], INTERVAL 50 days))
```

Comment: NTOdate is te_date column

Comment: Is this sql-server?
I don't recall the DATE_SUB function being in MS_SQL, I think it's from MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Datediff function: DateDiff(DD,'firstDate','SecondDate'). Here is the sample:

```
select [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].t_vrm,[ICPS].[dbo].[tickets] .t_zone_name, [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets] .t_street_name from  [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]  inner join 
      [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events] on [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_system_ref] = [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_number] 
where[ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_camera_ticket] = '0' and  [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_date_time_issued] >= convert(datetime,'2012/10/01',101)
      and [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_event_code] = '300' and 
     DateDiff(DD, [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_date_time_issued], [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_date]) >50)
```

Comment: Hi sonam thanks for quick reply but want to get   greater than 50 days where can i add it in diffdate column

Comment: If you mean difference between [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets] and [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_date] should be greater then 50 days then here is the code, also I've edited my answer as well.     DateDiff(DD, [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets].[t_date_time_issued], [ICPS].[dbo].[ticket_events].[te_date]) >50